# Using two sliding menus in a android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android and want to implement two slider menus in my project.I have done a tutorial found in this link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Can anyone suggest a way or give me a link as how to implement two slider menus in my project?

Answer (score -1):

You can use inbuilt navigation drawer for both side slidings.
Or
U can use slider (for slider check [example](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-slider-from-right-to-left.html) here)